# UICollectionView in UITableviewCell with Dynamic Data of CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to add eCommerce Homepage functionality to my app
Like Horizontal CollectionView(Slider) for each featured, special and selected category. I have implemented a special and featured category with slider but don't know how to add/handle dynamic data for other category collectionview ??

What i have..

```
var FeaturedProduct = [SubcatItemModel]()
var SpecialProduct = [SubcatItemModel]()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
   self.selectedProductForCart = self.products[indexPath.row].productId
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell") as! CategoryTableViewCell
        
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            //getFeaturedProduct()
            cell.MyheaderName.text = "FEATURED PRODUCTS"
        }
        
        cell.cCollectionView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.paleGrey.cgColor
        cell.cCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.cCollectionView.reloadData()
        print(String(cell.cCollectionView.tag))
        if(indexPath.row == 1){
            self.special = 1
        }else{
            self.special = 0
        }
        return cell
    }
```

//For CollectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(collectionView.tag == 0){
            return self.subcatModel.count
        }else if(collectionView.tag == 1){
            return self.SpecialProduct.count
        }else{
            return 2 //here is i want dynamic collectionview item for category products
        }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


let cell : RelatedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RelatedProducts", for: indexPath) as! RelatedCell
        
        let item = self.RelatedProduct[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.ProductName.text = item.name
        
        let modifiedUrl = item.image.replace(target: " ", withString:"%20")
        
        let urlll = URL(string:modifiedUrl)
        cell.productImage.kf.setImage(with: urlll, placeholder: UIImage(named: "noImagePlaceholder"))
        
        cell.ProductPrice.text = item.price
        
        return cell
}
```

Note: Other tutorial returning static collectionview size that i want dynamic.

[image]

Please Help....this problem makes me cry

Comment: Please share what you already tried and what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @Koen please check and let me know if anything other you need